# Get first two items from the first sublist if first element of the sublist is unique in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
df = [['apple', 'red', '0.2'], ['apple', 'green', '8.9'], ['apple', 'brown', '2.9'], 
      ['guava', 'green', '1.9'], ['guava', 'yellow', '4.9'], ['guava', 'light green', '2.3']]
```

From here I want to only get the first 2 items from the first distinct sublist given the condition that the value of the first sublist is unique.

Expected output:

```
df = [['apple', 'red'], ['guava', 'green']]
```

Code till now:

```
dummy_list = []

for item in df:
    if item[0] not in dummy_list:        
        dummy_list.append(item[:2])
```

This is not working and appending all the elements. Any help on this please

Comment: This would have worked if you would have another list for appending the results (e.g. `result_list`). The `setdefault` approach below might be the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or smarter : use a dict and `setdefault` to add the mapping only for the first

```
result = {}
for value in df:
    result.setdefault(value[0], value[:2])
result = list(result.values())

print(result)
```

Or you could keep a count of the added keys to avoid repeating them (in a separate list)

```
keys = set()
result = []
for value in df:
    if value[0] not in keys:
        result.append(value[:2])
        keys.add(value[0])

print(result) # [['apple', 'red'], ['guava', 'green']]
```

Comment: This is an excellent use case for the `setdefault`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and for the key use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

df = [['apple', 'red', '0.2'], ['apple', 'green', '8.9'], ['apple', 'brown', '2.9'], 
      ['guava', 'green', '1.9'], ['guava', 'yellow', '4.9'], ['guava', 'light green', '2.3']]

df1 = [next(g)[:2] for k, g in groupby(df, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

FYI `itemgetter(0)` is the same as `lambda x: x[0]` so you could use that too.

Answer (score 0):

When you say unique, do you mean that if you select a value, then you don't want to select it again?

If that is the case then pop might be useful:

```
import random as r
df = [['apple', 'red', '0.2'], ['apple', 'green', '8.9'], ['apple', 'brown', '2.9'], 
      ['guava', 'green', '1.9'], ['guava', 'yellow', '4.9'], ['guava', 'light green', '2.3']]

total = len(df)

targetdf = []

for value in range(2):
    position = r.randint(0,total-1)
    targetdf.append(df.pop(position)[:2])
    total-=1

#print(targetdf)

#[['apple', 'green'], ['guava', 'yellow']]
```

What this code does is that it selects a random position in the original list and then pops it out. This value is then saved to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `defaultdict` to store all the values using key-value pairs and then pick only the first value out of that list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = [
    ["apple", "red", "0.2"],
    ["apple", "green", "8.9"],
    ["apple", "brown", "2.9"],
    ["guava", "green", "1.9"],
    ["guava", "yellow", "4.9"],
    ["guava", "light green", "2.3"],
]
temp = defaultdict(list)
for sub_list in df:
    temp[sub_list[0]].append(sub_list)

df = [value[0][:2] for _, value in temp.items()]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'red'], ['guava', 'green']]
```